# No TCP connections to hosts behind VPN server (SYN, SYN-ACK, but no ACK), UDP, ICMP works

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vpn, routing, tcp, l2tp

I'm probably doing something incredibly stupid, but I just can't seem to figure out what. Here's what I'm trying to accomplish: I want remote users to be able to log into our network, so I set up a Windows 2008 Server as a VPN Server inside as a VM in XenCenter. Let's call him Benjamin. He's also doubling as a file server.

So far, what works:

- Remote VPN Login with Mac, Windows and iOS Clients
- Access to the file shares on Benjamin
- Ping to all hosts on the local network and on the internet, even with big packets (>1000 bytes)

What doesn't:
I can't establish any TCP connection (SSH, HTTP, …) to hosts on the local network besides Benjamin itself. In Wireshark, I can see the SYN and SYN-ACKs on both the client and the computer I'm trying to reach, but there's never an ACK. (Funnily, in the Wireshark Logs I prepared there are some DUP ACKs for some reason - and they are exactly the wrong way around than how it should be. I have no idea why.)

There was a problem before with even pinging anything besides Benjamin, but I solved that by disabling IP checksum offloading on Benjamin (somehow it didn't work and then packets would be thrown away).

I tried setting really small MTUs on my client, setting the gateway to Benjamin on the computer in the internal network any lots of other stuff, but nothing helped.

I suspect it's some kind of routing issue, but those ACKs are nowhere to be found. Any ideas? Where should I investigate further? Thanks in advance!

**Update**:
Weird thing I just discovered: When I try to ssh from the internal network into the VPN client, the client gets the SYN (I see it in Wireshark), but again, he never responds. I get the feeling that it has to be some configuration issue on the clients, but on *all* of them? And what could it be? There's no Firewall, and according to Wireshark, the packet looks valid (checksum and all). Does anyone know why it wouldn't respond to neither a SYN nor a SYN-ACK, when there's no firewall which could throw away those packets?

**Update 2**:
To add to the confusion, I've just confirmed that using netcat and **UDP**, everything works correctly, in both directions (nc listening on internal network host and on the VPN client). Maybe TCP just doesn't like me anymore?

Here's some more information:

```
Local net:   172.17.0.0/16
Router:     172.17.0.1 (Port Forwarding TCP 1701, UDP 500 and 4500)
XenServer:  172.17.0.10
Benjamin:   172.17.1.1
VPN DHCP range: 172.17.7.1..240
```

Wireshark log on the client (172.17.7.2 when in the VPN):

```
No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      1 0.000000    172.17.4.4            172.17.7.2            TCP      68     ssh > 61653 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1060 WS=4 TSval=1641695654 TSecr=440887504 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 1: 68 bytes on wire (544 bits), 68 bytes captured (544 bits)
Point-to-Point Protocol
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4), Dst: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: ssh (22), Dst Port: 61653 (61653), Seq: 0, Ack: 0, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      2 5.337197    172.17.7.2            172.17.4.4            TCP      68     61655 > ssh [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1240 WS=8 TSval=440887658 TSecr=0 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 2: 68 bytes on wire (544 bits), 68 bytes captured (544 bits)
Point-to-Point Protocol
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2), Dst: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 61655 (61655), Dst Port: ssh (22), Seq: 0, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      3 5.479947    172.17.4.4            172.17.7.2            TCP      68     ssh > 61655 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1060 WS=4 TSval=1641701208 TSecr=440887658 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 3: 68 bytes on wire (544 bits), 68 bytes captured (544 bits)
Point-to-Point Protocol
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4), Dst: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: ssh (22), Dst Port: 61655 (61655), Seq: 0, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      4 6.256638    172.17.7.2            172.17.4.4            TCP      68     61655 > ssh [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1240 WS=8 TSval=440887667 TSecr=0 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 4: 68 bytes on wire (544 bits), 68 bytes captured (544 bits)
Point-to-Point Protocol
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2), Dst: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 61655 (61655), Dst Port: ssh (22), Seq: 0, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      5 6.449901    172.17.4.4            172.17.7.2            TCP      56     [TCP Dup ACK 3#1] ssh > 61655 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=262140 Len=0 TSval=1641702152 TSecr=440887667

Frame 5: 56 bytes on wire (448 bits), 56 bytes captured (448 bits)
Point-to-Point Protocol
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4), Dst: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: ssh (22), Dst Port: 61655 (61655), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      6 6.609908    172.17.4.4            172.17.7.2            TCP      68     ssh > 61655 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1060 WS=4 TSval=1641702305 TSecr=440887667 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 6: 68 bytes on wire (544 bits), 68 bytes captured (544 bits)
Point-to-Point Protocol
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4), Dst: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: ssh (22), Dst Port: 61655 (61655), Seq: 0, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      7 7.258316    172.17.7.2            172.17.4.4            TCP      68     61655 > ssh [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1240 WS=8 TSval=440887677 TSecr=0 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 7: 68 bytes on wire (544 bits), 68 bytes captured (544 bits)
Point-to-Point Protocol
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2), Dst: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 61655 (61655), Dst Port: ssh (22), Seq: 0, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      8 7.450032    172.17.4.4            172.17.7.2            TCP      56     [TCP Dup ACK 6#1] ssh > 61655 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=262140 Len=0 TSval=1641703139 TSecr=440887677

Frame 8: 56 bytes on wire (448 bits), 56 bytes captured (448 bits)
Point-to-Point Protocol
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4), Dst: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: ssh (22), Dst Port: 61655 (61655), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      9 8.259938    172.17.7.2            172.17.4.4            TCP      68     61655 > ssh [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1240 WS=8 TSval=440887687 TSecr=0 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 9: 68 bytes on wire (544 bits), 68 bytes captured (544 bits)
Point-to-Point Protocol
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2), Dst: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 61655 (61655), Dst Port: ssh (22), Seq: 0, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     10 8.490122    172.17.4.4            172.17.7.2            TCP      56     [TCP Dup ACK 6#2] ssh > 61655 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=262140 Len=0 TSval=1641704143 TSecr=440887687

Frame 10: 56 bytes on wire (448 bits), 56 bytes captured (448 bits)
Point-to-Point Protocol
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4), Dst: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: ssh (22), Dst Port: 61655 (61655), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     11 9.249943    172.17.4.4            172.17.7.2            TCP      68     ssh > 61655 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1060 WS=4 TSval=1641704904 TSecr=440887687 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 11: 68 bytes on wire (544 bits), 68 bytes captured (544 bits)
Point-to-Point Protocol
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4), Dst: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: ssh (22), Dst Port: 61655 (61655), Seq: 0, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     12 9.261766    172.17.7.2            172.17.4.4            TCP      68     61655 > ssh [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1240 WS=8 TSval=440887697 TSecr=0 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 12: 68 bytes on wire (544 bits), 68 bytes captured (544 bits)
Point-to-Point Protocol
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2), Dst: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 61655 (61655), Dst Port: ssh (22), Seq: 0, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     13 9.430047    172.17.4.4            172.17.7.2            TCP      56     [TCP Dup ACK 11#1] ssh > 61655 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=262140 Len=0 TSval=1641705119 TSecr=440887697

Frame 13: 56 bytes on wire (448 bits), 56 bytes captured (448 bits)
Point-to-Point Protocol
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4), Dst: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: ssh (22), Dst Port: 61655 (61655), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     14 10.263852   172.17.7.2            172.17.4.4            TCP      68     61655 > ssh [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1240 WS=8 TSval=440887707 TSecr=0 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 14: 68 bytes on wire (544 bits), 68 bytes captured (544 bits)
Point-to-Point Protocol
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2), Dst: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 61655 (61655), Dst Port: ssh (22), Seq: 0, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     15 10.439839   172.17.4.4            172.17.7.2            TCP      56     [TCP Dup ACK 11#2] ssh > 61655 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=262140 Len=0 TSval=1641706132 TSecr=440887707

Frame 15: 56 bytes on wire (448 bits), 56 bytes captured (448 bits)
Point-to-Point Protocol
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4), Dst: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: ssh (22), Dst Port: 61655 (61655), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     16 12.267344   172.17.7.2            172.17.4.4            TCP      68     61655 > ssh [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1240 WS=8 TSval=440887727 TSecr=0 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 16: 68 bytes on wire (544 bits), 68 bytes captured (544 bits)
Point-to-Point Protocol
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2), Dst: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 61655 (61655), Dst Port: ssh (22), Seq: 0, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     17 12.469629   172.17.4.4            172.17.7.2            TCP      56     [TCP Dup ACK 11#3] ssh > 61655 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=262140 Len=0 TSval=1641708126 TSecr=440887727

Frame 17: 56 bytes on wire (448 bits), 56 bytes captured (448 bits)
Point-to-Point Protocol
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4), Dst: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: ssh (22), Dst Port: 61655 (61655), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     18 16.719912   172.17.4.4            172.17.7.2            TCP      68     ssh > 61653 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1060 WS=4 TSval=1641712353 TSecr=440887504 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 18: 68 bytes on wire (544 bits), 68 bytes captured (544 bits)
Point-to-Point Protocol
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4), Dst: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: ssh (22), Dst Port: 61653 (61653), Seq: 0, Ack: 0, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     19 21.679611   172.17.4.4            172.17.7.2            TCP      68     ssh > 61655 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1060 WS=4 TSval=1641717388 TSecr=440887727 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 19: 68 bytes on wire (544 bits), 68 bytes captured (544 bits)
Point-to-Point Protocol
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4), Dst: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: ssh (22), Dst Port: 61655 (61655), Seq: 0, Ack: 1, Len: 0
```

Wireshark log in the computer in the local network (172.17.4.4):

```
No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      1 0.000000    172.17.7.2            172.17.4.4            TCP      78     61655 > ssh [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1240 WS=8 TSval=440887658 TSecr=0 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 1: 78 bytes on wire (624 bits), 78 bytes captured (624 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec (c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec), Dst: Apple_4e:5b:ff (c8:2a:14:4e:5b:ff)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2), Dst: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 61655 (61655), Dst Port: ssh (22), Seq: 0, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      2 0.000102    172.17.4.4            172.17.7.2            TCP      78     ssh > 61655 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1060 WS=4 TSval=1641701208 TSecr=440887658 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 2: 78 bytes on wire (624 bits), 78 bytes captured (624 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: Apple_4e:5b:ff (c8:2a:14:4e:5b:ff), Dst: c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec (c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4), Dst: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: ssh (22), Dst Port: 61655 (61655), Seq: 0, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      3 0.950403    172.17.7.2            172.17.4.4            TCP      78     61655 > ssh [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1240 WS=8 TSval=440887667 TSecr=0 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 3: 78 bytes on wire (624 bits), 78 bytes captured (624 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec (c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec), Dst: Apple_4e:5b:ff (c8:2a:14:4e:5b:ff)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2), Dst: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 61655 (61655), Dst Port: ssh (22), Seq: 0, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      4 0.950567    172.17.4.4            172.17.7.2            TCP      66     [TCP Dup ACK 2#1] ssh > 61655 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=262140 Len=0 TSval=1641702152 TSecr=440887667

Frame 4: 66 bytes on wire (528 bits), 66 bytes captured (528 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: Apple_4e:5b:ff (c8:2a:14:4e:5b:ff), Dst: c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec (c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4), Dst: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: ssh (22), Dst Port: 61655 (61655), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      5 1.104130    172.17.4.4            172.17.7.2            TCP      78     ssh > 61655 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1060 WS=4 TSval=1641702305 TSecr=440887667 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 5: 78 bytes on wire (624 bits), 78 bytes captured (624 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: Apple_4e:5b:ff (c8:2a:14:4e:5b:ff), Dst: c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec (c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4), Dst: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: ssh (22), Dst Port: 61655 (61655), Seq: 0, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      6 1.940779    172.17.7.2            172.17.4.4            TCP      78     61655 > ssh [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1240 WS=8 TSval=440887677 TSecr=0 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 6: 78 bytes on wire (624 bits), 78 bytes captured (624 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec (c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec), Dst: Apple_4e:5b:ff (c8:2a:14:4e:5b:ff)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2), Dst: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 61655 (61655), Dst Port: ssh (22), Seq: 0, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      7 1.940962    172.17.4.4            172.17.7.2            TCP      66     [TCP Dup ACK 5#1] ssh > 61655 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=262140 Len=0 TSval=1641703139 TSecr=440887677

Frame 7: 66 bytes on wire (528 bits), 66 bytes captured (528 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: Apple_4e:5b:ff (c8:2a:14:4e:5b:ff), Dst: c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec (c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4), Dst: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: ssh (22), Dst Port: 61655 (61655), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      8 2.950009    172.17.7.2            172.17.4.4            TCP      78     61655 > ssh [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1240 WS=8 TSval=440887687 TSecr=0 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 8: 78 bytes on wire (624 bits), 78 bytes captured (624 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec (c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec), Dst: Apple_4e:5b:ff (c8:2a:14:4e:5b:ff)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2), Dst: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 61655 (61655), Dst Port: ssh (22), Seq: 0, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      9 2.950198    172.17.4.4            172.17.7.2            TCP      66     [TCP Dup ACK 5#2] ssh > 61655 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=262140 Len=0 TSval=1641704143 TSecr=440887687

Frame 9: 66 bytes on wire (528 bits), 66 bytes captured (528 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: Apple_4e:5b:ff (c8:2a:14:4e:5b:ff), Dst: c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec (c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4), Dst: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: ssh (22), Dst Port: 61655 (61655), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     10 3.714242    172.17.4.4            172.17.7.2            TCP      78     ssh > 61655 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1060 WS=4 TSval=1641704904 TSecr=440887687 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 10: 78 bytes on wire (624 bits), 78 bytes captured (624 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: Apple_4e:5b:ff (c8:2a:14:4e:5b:ff), Dst: c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec (c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4), Dst: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: ssh (22), Dst Port: 61655 (61655), Seq: 0, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     11 3.929627    172.17.7.2            172.17.4.4            TCP      78     61655 > ssh [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1240 WS=8 TSval=440887697 TSecr=0 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 11: 78 bytes on wire (624 bits), 78 bytes captured (624 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec (c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec), Dst: Apple_4e:5b:ff (c8:2a:14:4e:5b:ff)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2), Dst: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 61655 (61655), Dst Port: ssh (22), Seq: 0, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     12 3.929819    172.17.4.4            172.17.7.2            TCP      66     [TCP Dup ACK 10#1] ssh > 61655 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=262140 Len=0 TSval=1641705119 TSecr=440887697

Frame 12: 66 bytes on wire (528 bits), 66 bytes captured (528 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: Apple_4e:5b:ff (c8:2a:14:4e:5b:ff), Dst: c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec (c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4), Dst: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: ssh (22), Dst Port: 61655 (61655), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     13 4.949931    172.17.7.2            172.17.4.4            TCP      78     61655 > ssh [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1240 WS=8 TSval=440887707 TSecr=0 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 13: 78 bytes on wire (624 bits), 78 bytes captured (624 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec (c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec), Dst: Apple_4e:5b:ff (c8:2a:14:4e:5b:ff)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2), Dst: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 61655 (61655), Dst Port: ssh (22), Seq: 0, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     14 4.950122    172.17.4.4            172.17.7.2            TCP      66     [TCP Dup ACK 10#2] ssh > 61655 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=262140 Len=0 TSval=1641706132 TSecr=440887707

Frame 14: 66 bytes on wire (528 bits), 66 bytes captured (528 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: Apple_4e:5b:ff (c8:2a:14:4e:5b:ff), Dst: c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec (c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4), Dst: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: ssh (22), Dst Port: 61655 (61655), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     15 6.950093    172.17.7.2            172.17.4.4            TCP      78     61655 > ssh [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1240 WS=8 TSval=440887727 TSecr=0 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 15: 78 bytes on wire (624 bits), 78 bytes captured (624 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec (c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec), Dst: Apple_4e:5b:ff (c8:2a:14:4e:5b:ff)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2), Dst: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 61655 (61655), Dst Port: ssh (22), Seq: 0, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     16 6.950281    172.17.4.4            172.17.7.2            TCP      66     [TCP Dup ACK 10#3] ssh > 61655 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=262140 Len=0 TSval=1641708126 TSecr=440887727

Frame 16: 66 bytes on wire (528 bits), 66 bytes captured (528 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: Apple_4e:5b:ff (c8:2a:14:4e:5b:ff), Dst: c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec (c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4), Dst: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: ssh (22), Dst Port: 61655 (61655), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     17 7.955752    172.17.4.4            172.17.7.2            TCP      78     ssh > 61655 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1060 WS=4 TSval=1641709126 TSecr=440887727 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 17: 78 bytes on wire (624 bits), 78 bytes captured (624 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: Apple_4e:5b:ff (c8:2a:14:4e:5b:ff), Dst: c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec (c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4), Dst: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: ssh (22), Dst Port: 61655 (61655), Seq: 0, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     18 11.196585   172.17.4.4            172.17.7.2            TCP      78     ssh > 61653 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1060 WS=4 TSval=1641712353 TSecr=440887504 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 18: 78 bytes on wire (624 bits), 78 bytes captured (624 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: Apple_4e:5b:ff (c8:2a:14:4e:5b:ff), Dst: c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec (c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4), Dst: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: ssh (22), Dst Port: 61653 (61653), Seq: 0, Ack: 0, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     19 16.252632   172.17.4.4            172.17.7.2            TCP      78     ssh > 61655 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1060 WS=4 TSval=1641717388 TSecr=440887727 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 19: 78 bytes on wire (624 bits), 78 bytes captured (624 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: Apple_4e:5b:ff (c8:2a:14:4e:5b:ff), Dst: c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec (c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.4.4 (172.17.4.4), Dst: 172.17.7.2 (172.17.7.2)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: ssh (22), Dst Port: 61655 (61655), Seq: 0, Ack: 1, Len: 0
```

Potentially related server fault questions, but didn't help me so far:

[PPTP-Gateway routes icmp but no http](https://serverfault.com/questions/171291/pptp-gateway-routes-icmp-but-no-http)

[SNAT through Racoon IPSec VPN](https://serverfault.com/questions/307530/snat-through-racoon-ipsec-vpn)

[Linux fails to interpret ACK, keeps resending SYN+ACK](https://serverfault.com/questions/292617/linux-fails-to-interpret-ack-keeps-resending-synack)

Answer (score 2):

I would start by taking a look at your masking.  If the general hosts are in 172.17.0.0/16 and your VPN subnet is in 172.17.7.0/24 then it's entirely possible for there to be some uncertain connectivity situations.

A general host in 172.17.0.0/16 when sending a packet to a VPN host in 172.17.7.0/24 will attempt to ARP for the VPN host's address (rather than sending it to a gateway).

The VPN host, in turn, tries to send a frame to a host in the general subnet.  It's going to send via its gateway.  If this gateway is a member of both the /24 and the /16 then you've got a similar problem - either it's an illegal configuration or the packet is actually being bridged rather than routed.

It's possible you have proxy-arp configured - that would cause a routing device to answer ARP requests in the larger subnet for a host it has a route to, but this isn't clear from your posted materials.

It's also possible that you have bridging set up somewhere in the mix.  This could yield some strange situations as a standard ARP would work in one direction but in the other some sort of gateway would be called upon to forward a nominally routed frame back out the receiving interface - which, again, might work in some circumstances but isn't good (nb - this could be a source of duplicate ACK's).

Can you put your VPN hosts in a non-overlapping subnet?  Say give it a 172.18.x.x address and then configure routing between the gateway for this new subnet and the default gateway for 172.17.0.0/16?  At a minimum this would make the whole thing simpler to troubleshoot and it very well might fix things.

Comment: I've updated my original post to correct an error - it's not actually a 172.17.7.0/24 subnet but rather the same /16 mask, it's just that the Windows Server assigns VPN clients IP from 172.17.7.1 to .240. As you mentioned ARP: I see on my internal host that in his routing table, he has an entry like this: `172.17.7.7         c6:4f:51:a3:48:ec  UHLWIi          0        2     en0   1196`. I guess that MAC address belongs somehow to the Windows Server, but how can I verify that? `ipconfig /all` gives me nothing. I'll try your suggestion with the different subnet now. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, so the VPN clients now get IPs from the 172.18.x.x range. When I added a static route on the router for 172.18.0.0/16 -> 172.17.1.1 pings started to work again, but it didn't change anything for TCP. Any additional info I could provide that might help? Any clue why those DUP ACKs seem to be coming from the internal host?